# How to access a variable in a file from a Linux Service file

Tags: linux, files, rhel, configuration, services

I have a Red hat 7 Service file(.service) and i need to access some data in a file, i used to access data from a pom file but now i have to access a conf file, a file that's key and value.

Example: port = 8080

I need to know how to access and read the data in the conf and use it the service file

Comment: use `grep` to grab it from that file

Comment: so i would have to execute in a ExecStartPre.
but can i load the result into a constant to then use it in the ExecStart?
or do i have to do it directly in ExecStart?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634104/272848

Comment: i'm reading it.

Comment: i have answered there