# Execute a linux command in a a Enviroment sentence in a service file

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, services

I have this `.service` file. In `ExecStart` I need to pass some parameters which I figured I could set in the Environment as variables, but first I must obtain them from a `.conf` file with a `grep` and a `cut`.

But I need to know if I can perform a Linux command sentence in the Environment so I can get the values from my `.conf` file.

```
Environment=(here would be the code for the variables)
ExecStart=(here i would use them)
```

Comment: From the manual page (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html): "Empty lines, **lines without an "=" separator**, or lines starting with ; or # will be ignored". So the answer is no.

Comment: I would try creating an environment file (`EnvironmentFile` clause) with an `ExecStartPre`, but perhaps `systemd` reads the environment file before it performs the `ExecStartPre` command. If so, I would make a second service that creates the environment file and make the original service dependent on it.

Comment: I would point your `ExecStart=` at a wrapper script that sets up the environment, then calls your program.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify an existing `EnvironmentFile` in `ExecStartPre` and have it take effect in `ExecStart`:

`~/.config/systemd/user/envtest.service`:

```
[Unit]
Desciption=Test EnvironmentFile usage

[Service]
Type=oneshot
#
# An environment file can be used to set a bunch of variables 
# %t is a runtime directory, The location is arbitary so use what
# works for you.
EnvironmentFile=%t/envtest.environment
#
# We will edit the environment file from this bash script.
# The file itself is passed as an argument into the script.
# This line will fail to start if the EnvironmentFile doesn't
# exist yet. So it might be better to have a permanent file 
# somewhere such as `/var/lib`. 
ExecStartPre=%h/bin/create_environment.sh %t/envtest.environment
#
# The environment file will be re-read and applied to the service
# I am using simply using `env` to print out the current environment
# so we can see whether the contents of our EnvironmentFile are used
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env
```

`~/bin/create_environment.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add your `grep *.conf | cut > $1` here
# This variable is for demonstration
echo "TestVariable=Added" > $1
```

Running this shows that it fails if the `EnvironmentFile=` doesn't exist.  However if we create the file first (maybe you want it to live in `/var` where it will persist between boots), then we can start the service.

```
$ systemctl --user start envtest.service
...
Feb 12 14:47:59 stewbian systemd[992]: envtest.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
Feb 12 14:47:59 stewbian systemd[992]: envtest.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: No such file or directory

$ touch /run/user/$UID/envtest.environment
$ systemctl --user start envtest.service
$ journalctl --user -u evntest.service | grep TestVariable
Feb 12 14:49:10 stewbian envtest[261219]: TestVariable=Added
```

We can see from the output of `journalctl` that the service printed `TestVariable=Added`. This means the `EnvironmentVariable` was read between our `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStart` and our changes to the file appear in the service's environment.

The only caveat is that your `EnvironmentFile` must exist before the service is run (so probably don't use `%T`/`/tmp` or `%t`/`/run` like I did).

---

**UPDATE based on OP's comments**: By setting variables in `EnvironmentVariable`, your application has access to them whenever it tries to read an environment variable (i.e. [getenv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)).  In your comments, you suggest that you also intend to use the variables in the command line invocation like so:

```
ExecStart=/path/to/bin/app --host=$HOST --port=$PORT
```

People often make the mistake of adding `bash` syntax to `ExecStart`, however fortunatly [environment variable substitution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html#COMMAND_LINES) is one of the few shell-style features which is supported. If used as a single-word `$PORT` will be replaced.  In the case above, you need to be more explicit and use `${PORT}` which works even when the variable is part of a word.  Demonstration below:

```
$ cat ~/bin/create_environment.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "HOST=127.0.0.1" > $1
echo "PORT=11111" >> $1

$ systemctl --user cat envtest.service
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/envtest.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
EnvironmentFile=%t/envtest.environment
ExecStartPre=%h/bin/create_environment.sh %t/envtest.environment
ExecStart=/bin/echo --host=${HOST} --port=${PORT}

$ touch /run/user/$UID/envtest.environment
$ systemctl --user start envtest.service
$ journalctl --user -u envtest.service | grep echo
Feb 12 21:28:00 stewbian echo[268399]: --host=127.0.0.1 --port=11111
```

You can see that `echo` properly printed the values of `HOST` and `PORT` which we set in our `EnvironmentFile` via the script set up in `ExecStartPre`.

Comment: with EnviromentFile , can i access the variables like i would in Enviroment?
Because i then would have to do something like: ExecStart=... -Dhost=$host...

Comment: Yes, that does work.  It's called "Environment Variable Substitution" and it's one of the few shell-like features that systemd performs when parsing `ExecStart`. I've updated my answer to give you a demonstration.

Comment: I worked on this problem for about 4 hours and couldn't find a solution until I found this answer -- **thank you** so much. I ended up creating a bash script in the $HOME/bin directory of the user that runs my service. As suggested, i then ran that script in an **ExecStartPre** and that bash script populated a file that's referenced in my service as the **EnvironmentFile** -- worked first try. Thank you!